# What's the difference between frost, hoar-frost, rime, rime ice?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

What's the difference between **frost**, **hoar-frost**, **rime**, **rime ice**?

They look similar, but is there really a difference between them?

**Context:**

> *"bushes covered with **frost**"*

> *"the **hoarfrost** formed a delicate swirly pattern on the window"*

> *"There was a strong **rime** on all vegetation."*

> *"The town looked like a lunar landscape, with everything covered in **rime ice**."*

*Thank you in advance!*

Edit: **Links to the definitions:**
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/frost_1

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hoarfrost

https://www.google.com/search?q=define+rime&oq=define+rime&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l3j0i10i22i30l3j0i10i22i30i395.4867j1j7&client=ms-android-vf-ro-revc&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Have you looked up the words in a dictionary? Why should we have to do all the work??

Comment: Welcome! 1) Yes, please edit to show what you find in dictionaries. For one thing, it will help us supplement them better. 2) Be aware that some of these are much less common than others. Not invalid, but rare. "Frost" is extremely common; "hour-frost" much less so, and "rime" fairly obscure (I once tried to use "rimy" in a magazine article and the editor changed it to "grimy"). I haven't actually heard the usage "rime ice" before.

Comment: A dictionary will tell you the differences.  What sort of audience are you writing for?  For a general audience, "frost" will probably work in all contexts.  For a specialist meteorologist, there is a technical difference.  What experience do you have with frost?  Do you come from a country in which frost is common?

Comment: The word *hoar* is also used alone. M-W  *b : a covering of minute ice crystals on a cold surface *.

Comment: This is a science question, not an English language question.

Comment: Please put the TEXT of the definitions into the question, not just the links. Nobody should have to have four browsers open to understand the question. Also, considering you cannot answer it with dictionary definitions and Google searches, please say exactly what you're expecting from answerers that goes beyond what you've already found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little like asking for the meaning of "cat", "serval" and "ocelot".  Most people know that ocelots and servals are types of wild cat, but couldn't  distinguish them.

Frost is a general term for the ice that forms on many things when the temperature is below zero. This is normally the word to use. It is distinguished from "snow" (which falls from the sky) and the ice that grows on puddles, ponds, and lakes.

Hoar, or hoarfrost is a type of frost. It has a "feathery" appearance. It forms when water vapour changes directly to ice.

Rime is a type of frost, it forms when water droplets in mist touch cold objects and freeze. It tends to be harder than hoar.  It can also be a verb meaning "to cover with frost"

In non-technical language, there is a lot of technically inaccurate use.  Most people don't inspect frost closely enough to decide if it is hoar or rime, and don't really know the technical definitions. In your examples,  the window ice isn't technically hoarfrost, and it is common enough to see examples like "rimed with hoarfrost".

So for many people, these are "types of frost" but they don't know the difference between them.